# How to print attributes in python. it is printing location. but i need to print ''25"

Tags: python

It should print a number, not location.

```
a=25
class me:
    def it(a):
        print(a)
m=me()
m.it()
```

I should get 25, but I am getting - `<__main__.me object at 0x7f98cb648b70>`

Comment: Your class dont have atributes. "A" is just a global variable, put in inside class

Comment: `def it(self):` change a to self to fix the reference

Comment: For me the question is unclear. It looks like the OP is missing some general knowledge about classes.

Answer (score 1):

This should be theclass, a have to be inside class, I def set/get methods

```
class me:

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a      

    def set_a(self, v):
        self.a = v

    def get_a(self):
        return self.a

m = me(5)

m.get_a()
m.set_a(12)
m.get_a()
```

Output

```
5
12
```

Comment: With your first `get_a` you access the class attribute `a`.  Then you set an instance attribute `a` with `set_a`, then you retrieve the instance attribute. Why do you mix class and instance attributes?

Comment: @Matthias I dont understand what you means, a is attribute of the class me, I dont mix anything. Set_a only asign value. Can you suggest changes? pd: To be a complete class I miss the init function also

Comment: With your first `get_a` you access `me.a`. Then with `set_a` you set `m.a` (while `me.a` still exists). The second `get_a` accesses the now existing instance attribute `m.a`. I have the feeling that you should brush up your knowledge of the difference between [class attributes and instance attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables). To cite the documentation: "Generally speaking, instance variables are for data unique to each instance and class variables are for attributes and methods shared by all instances of the class"

Answer (score 0):

In your case `it` method is considered as `instance method` and for `instance method` 1st parameter is always an instance(`self`). So when you do `print(a)` it's printing location of an instance instead of printing value of variable `a`.

You can declare `it` method as static like below

```
a=25
class me:
    @staticmethod
    def it():
        print(a)
m=me()
m.it()
```

Or you can do

```
a=25
class me:
    def it(self):
        print(a)
m=me()
m.it()
```